# Trouble getting value of data attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to modify [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/) tutorial to add in social network links. Here is the markup for the tile:

```
<li>
                    <a href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/" 
data-largesrc="http://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/ImageSlider/21centuryimages/logos/ALDI.png" data-title="ALDI" 
data-facebook="http://www.facebook.com" 
data-description="" >
                        <img src="images/aldi.png" alt="img01"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

And as you can see, I've included a data attribute of `data-facebook`. I went into the JS file and added the facebook lines to the following:

```
var $itemEl = this.$item.children( 'a' ),
            eldata = {
                href : $itemEl.attr( 'href' ),
                largesrc : $itemEl.data( 'largesrc' ),
                title : $itemEl.data( 'title' ),
                description : $itemEl.data( 'description' ),
                facebook : $itemEl.data( 'facebook' )
            };

        this.$title.html( eldata.title );
        this.$description.html( eldata.description );
        this.$facebook.html( eldata.facebook );
        this.$href.attr( 'href', eldata.href );
```

When I save it and try it in Chrome, when I click the tile that shows the expanded information container, it takes me to the the `href` attribute instead. I'm not sure why adding those two lines messes it up. More specifically I've traced the line that actually makes the tile behave differently to `this.$facebook.html( eldata.facebook );`. Could you guys take a look at what I've done and see if I've made a glaring error? I've never done something like this so I'm new to it. Here is the site where you can check it out: http://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/matt/grid/index.html

Thanks!

Comment: `this.$facebook` is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed to adjust the `create()` method

```
create : function() {
    // create Preview structure:
    this.$title = $( '<h3></h3>' );
    this.$description = $( '<p></p>' );
    this.$href = $( '<a href="#">Visit website</a>' );
    this.$details = $( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$title, this.$description, this.$href );
    this.$loading = $( '<div class="og-loading"></div>' );
    this.$fullimage = $( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$loading );
    this.$closePreview = $( '<span class="og-close"></span>' );
    this.$previewInner = $( '<div class="og-expander-inner"></div>' ).append( this.$closePreview, this.$fullimage, this.$details );
    this.$previewEl = $( '<div class="og-expander"></div>' ).append( this.$previewInner );
    // append preview element to the item
    this.$item.append( this.getEl() );
    // set the transitions for the preview and the item
    if( support ) {
        this.setTransition();
    }
}
```

Add an element for `$facebook` and it should work.

Comment: I did add in `this.$facebook` at the end of the `this.$details` line, but I think this just creates the HTML for it. And it isn't responsible for breaking it. If I replace `this.$facebook` with `"http://www.facebook.com/"` it displays properly.

Comment: You're using `this.$facebook.html(...)` without defining `this.$facebook` which generates an error when clicking on a tile (as you can observe when viewing the console in the moment you click on a tile). Add `this.$facebook = $("<div />")` for example

Comment: Okay I did that and it fixed the site from following the link and showing the expander. And then to actually get to show the facebook link, how would I do that?

Comment: Do you think I could get a little more help from you? I'm having trouble adjusting the height of the expanded container. I don't like how tall it is. I can tell that it is generated with javascript based on the height of the window and a few other things. But I'm not terribly versed in JS and having difficulties. The new link is http://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/about/ncp.shtml. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Inspect the elements (firebug, developer tools, dragonfly, ...) and you will see where to change the styles to fit your needs - e.g. class `superbox-show` in style.css

Answer (score 0):

```
var $itemEl = this.$item.children( 'a' )
```

Returns a list of all the `anchor` tags for each `li`. Looks like it is returning more than one entry

Comment: But there is only one `anchor` tag per `li`?

Comment: But there are multiple `li's` right.. So if `this.$item` corresponds to an `li` then this would fail